# Is there a way to calculate spatial theil sen slope on matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a 3D (lon x lat x time) matrix and want to get the slope at each grid point i.e a matrix of lon x lat with each element being the slope along the time dimension.

I found the Theil_sen_regress function and when using the code below I get Nans.

```
% dimensions
lati= 100;
long = 180;
time=37;

years = 1982:2018; % the vector of years

data=rand(lati, long, time);
sen_slopes = zeros(long, lati);

for i=1:long
    for j=1:lati
        m = Theil_Sen_Regress(years,reshape(data(i, j, :),1,[]));
        slopes(i, j) = m(1);
    end
end
```

I am not sure what I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks